# SAS: How to split data into subsets with names in sequence.

Tags: sas, subset

I am using SAS to split dataset into subsets with the following naming convention: sub001, sub002, sub003 ....  My dataset looks like

```
ID   var1
AA   ...
AA   ...
AB   ...
AC   ...
...  ...
AZ   ...
...  ...
ZZ   ...
```

I could do this manually.

```
data sub001 sub002.....sub676;
set data;
if id='AA' then output sub001;
.....
if id='ZZ' then output sub676;
run;
```

But is there any easy way to do this ? I assume `%macro` or `%do` could help here.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also, are you sure you want to do this? Often splitting data like this is an inefficient  solution. If you describe why you want to split the data, people may give you better alternatives.

Comment: Does each value of ID become its own subset?  If so why not just use BY ID statements on later analysis rather than making many small datasets?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to split them all into a bunch of datasets, you can use a macro to do so. This is one of my favorite little tricks in macro programming:

**Step 1: Read all distinct IDs into a space-separated macro variable**

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct strip(upcase(id) )
    into :all_ids separated by ' '
    from have;
quit;
```

**Step 2: Loop over the total words in `&all_ids`, filter `have` on each value of &all_ids**

```
options nonotes;

%macro split;
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&all_ids) );
        data sub_&i;
            set have;
            where upcase(ID) = "%scan(&all_ids, &i)";
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
%split;

options notes;
```

Because we are looping over the total number of words in the space-delimited macro variable `&all_ids`, there is a 1-1 correspondence between the value of `&i` and the position of each word in `&all_ids`. For example:

```
 &i  |        &all_ids      
LOOP   WORD NUMBER      WORD           
 1         1             AA
 2         2             AB
 3         3             AC
```

This isn't the most efficient way to do it since we are writing a new dataset to the disk every time, but unless your resources are extremely limited or you have a monstrous dataset in the hundreds and hundreds of gigabytes or more, it should complete quickly. If you need a way to do it with less I/O, I can help you with that as well.